Issue with Deploying Java Spring Project to Server using GitHub Actions and Docker
I'm trying to set up automatic deployment of my Java Spring project to a server using GitHub Actions and Docker, but I'm encountering some issues. Here's my current workflow:
name: Build and Deploy Spring API
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-deploy:
    name: Build and Deploy Spring API
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup JDK 18
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'corretto'
          java-version: 18

      - name: Unit tests
        run: mvn -B test --file pom.xml

      - name: Build the app
        run: |
          mvn clean
          mvn -B package --file pom.xml

      - name: Build the Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/rest-api:latest

      - name: SSH to server and deploy
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SERVER_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SERVER_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          script: |
            docker-compose down
            docker-compose pull
            docker-compose up -d


Problem:
After successfully building the Docker image (Dockerfile is located in the root of my project), it doesn't deploy to my server. Additionally, I encountered the following error related to Docker tag reference format during the build process:
/usr/bin/docker buildx build --iidfile /tmp/docker-actions-toolkit-zr5tOL/iidfile --tag /rest-api:latest --metadata-file /tmp/docker-actions-toolkit-zr5tOL/metadata-file --push .
ERROR: invalid tag "/rest-api:latest": invalid reference format
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: invalid tag "/rest-api:latest": invalid reference format

I've verified that all secrets and SSH settings are correctly configured. How can I resolve these issues and ensure that the Docker image deploys correctly to the server?
Previously, I tried using the following workflow:
name: Deploy to Server

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main 

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

    - name: Build and push Docker image
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        context: .
        push: true
        tags: your-dockerhub-username/your-app-name:latest
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}

    - name: Deploy to server
      env:
        SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      run: |
        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@your-server-ip << 'EOF'
          docker-compose -f Docker-compose.yaml down
          docker-compose -f Docker-compose.yaml pull
          docker-compose -f Docker-compose.yaml up -d
        EOF


However, I faced an issue where it couldn't find the COPY target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar step.
Here are my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml:
Dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:18-slim

# Install Maven
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y maven && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN mvn clean package -Pdocker

COPY target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]


docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:11-alpine"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres

  backend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres

I've verified that all secrets and SSH settings are correctly configured. How can I resolve these issues and ensure that the Docker image deploys correctly to the server?

Regarding your "additional problem"
(since I do not have the reputation yet do make an acutal comment)
ERROR: invalid tag "/rest-api:latest": invalid reference format

Your first-metioned GitHub Action says that this
${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/rest-api:latest should be resolved as your tag (image name). Due to the error message is seems that ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }} was resolved as an empty string ("").
Please re-check the presence and correct substitution of secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME.
Since the image could not be tag with that name; only the generic image id could be pushed (if nothing), which surely is not used in your compose as the image. I think if you hardcode the tag name (as a workaround) like you did in your second-mentioned GitHub Action, it will work.
As of current docker tag documentation the format must follow [HOST[:PORT_NUMBER]/]PATH while PATH is defined as [NAMESPACE/]REPOSITORY.
I assume that your second GitHub Action did not have the error, right?
Because there you hardcoded the tag with your-dockerhub-username/your-app-name:latest.
